# enable Powershell script execution on domain

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, gpo, executionpolicy

I am working on a mid-size Windows 2012 R2 domain right now, and slapped together a PowerShell login script.

But I can't figure out how to allow regular users to run it!

By default, PowerShell script execution is disabled in a Windows domain.
I am trying to enable script execution using group policies.

I found several sets on instructions, but none have yet yielded the result desired.  Here is an example of the instructions I have found:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2015/01/02/execution-policy-and-group-policy/

So far no amount of `gpupdate /force` or rebooting seems to work.
Does anyone have first hand experience at enabling script execution using group policies?

Comment: I have used this policy before and it works. If it doesn't work for you you need to provide a lot more information about your actual policy setting, how/where they policy is applied, and the RSoP. Preferably on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) where this question belongs.

Comment: I got around this as a temporary measure previously, by running a batch file with `powershell.exe -file "C:\File.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` instead of running the powershell script directly.